# Dynamically creating dropdown elements and text using data from a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get my head around dynamically creating elements on a page from a database and pushing them onto a table element. I understand I can do this by jquery, but I'm unsure if I need to build this data before hand and hide/show data accordingly.

So first I have my first dropdown menu, which I populate from the data grabbed from the database using php;

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownmenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Select Item
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <?php
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                    {
                        echo '<li><a href="#" id ="showlogs"><b>ItemId:</b> ' . $row['id'] . '</a></li>'; 
                    }
            ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a javascript onclick event which updates the dropdown as to what is currently selected;

```
<script>
    $('#showlogs').click(function(){
        $('#dropdownmenu').text($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

The next step I am looking to do is depending on what is selected from the drop down menu, populate a blank table (with a default non-selected) with the results for a DB query using php based on the dropdown menu contents, e.g. SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id = (ItemId from currently selected)

Default table;

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">Date</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">View</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">None Selected</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any advice would be amazing :) Thanks

Comment: First question: Is there a reason why you are using somekind of a custom dropdownlist element with DIVs and UL>LI instead of using a SELECT and OPTION tag?

Comment: Add the `BOOTSTRAP` TAG please...

Comment: oh I get it. Didn't realised on the spot it was the bootstrap component

Comment: @IndieRok No reason in particular, I'm just going off the default bootstrap example code, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @user2321428 There is a pair of native HTML tag for a dropdown menu and the options within called SELECT and OPTION. The bootstrap dropdown class is better suited for navigation menus and the like, not an input form.

Comment: Like Chris and Blag said, I would highly recommend using a SELECT tag instead. This way, with the help of jquery, you could bind an "On Change event" more easily to that element. With this, being able to get the ID from a selected option, you could have an Ajax call to a php file in order to query your database and return the results for display in your page (as Blag suggested in is answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Blag said use a select tag with an event listener to trigger your AJAX request.

```
<select id="optionList">
   <option>...</option>
</select>
```

then

```
$("#optionList").on("change", function(){
    //do something
});
```

Full with AJAX:

```
$("#optionList").on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "outsideScript.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            itemSelected : $("#optionList").val()
        },
        success: function(result){
            $("#myDiv").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

ex.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LucasCarioca/9b3h6f9e/9/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would the correct next step to be grab the current value in the option box and append the html in the table?

Comment: yes the would the best way to do it. You can grab the value then use an ajax request to update the table one the request is complete. 
$("<div where table should go>").html(<new table data>);

Comment: I just updated with the AJAX piece

Comment: Awesome, I've pretty much got the ajax down now, my last hurdle is once I have the value from the selected box, I need to transfer this to php to grab the data out of the database. I know I can't use the javascript variable, is there a better way to perform this? Maybe grabbing the currently selected text in php?

Comment: With my example of the ajax request, you place the php code that will do that in the "outsideScript.php" file then pass the value through that 'request. So on the php script you can do $itemSelected = $_POST['itemSelected']; to get the value. The then echo out the html that should go in the div.

Comment: I also recommend you looking into AngularJS. Makes this kind of work real easy.

Comment: Working as expected, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should do it.

- [Bootstrap dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) is for making menu, with hard link `<a href=""></a>` to other page.
- If you want to make an AJAX page that'll load something from user choice, [then use a `SELECT`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects)